# Diodes forward bias voltage

Tags: diodes

Why the forward bias voltage of a silicon diode is 0.7V?If we apply a voltage of 0.1V then the depletion region will be minimized.In a diode there is the chemical potential which creates diffusion and there is the electrostatic potential created by the donor and acceptor ions.So if we apply a small voltage which will help the cjemical potential then the majority charge carriers of the n-type semiconductor will diffuse into the p-type semiconductor and the depletion will be destroyed.Where am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome. What specifically do you not understand? What is confusing? Chemical potential? The forward Vdrop has to do with things like band-gap voltage, for a given compound. For Germanium the band-gap voltage is lower. We are drifting a bit into Physics 101, down at the electron level.

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.